# How to find the mobile current location without using gprs?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

I have created an android application, in which i have to find the current location of the mobile. For example using my application i have to find my friends current location.If i enter the mobile number the current location of my friend has to be shown in map.Its not necessary that my friend mobile to be smart phone. How can i track them using their phone number without using GPRS? Please help me.

Comment: Without Internet Connection, How exactly you are getting your friend's location ?

Comment: You can call him up and ask him.

Comment: Now SO Users provide Crazy Rocket Solution over here. Crazy Question with Crazy Answer.

Comment: Seriously, most of june's questions are, "i wont try anything, just ask questions, hoping someone will just google for me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Location if you have **Internet Connection(GPRS or WIFI)**, otherwise you Can not get Location, Because to get Location, your Phone need to communicate with (Google Maps) and then they get your **Longitude/Latitude** and then give you the facility.
If you need to check your Friend's Location, for that you need **your Friend Latitude/longitude** Information.
But you must have **Internet Connection**.

Comment: @navees ahmad how to find my friends latitude and longitude information through my mobile?

Comment: @june its depend on your application, in most of this type applications, developers involve server, in that server (you and friends accounts will be created on your email/number basis) and then when you login in that application, and your location will be get through google maps, and after that your latitude/longitude values will be sent to the server.
when you want to find your's friend location so the application will get the saved latitude/longitude values, and will show you on the mapView.

Comment: Kindly Accept the answer bro @june so others can find the correct direction